# Asus uefi firmware is not detecting the bootable disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, uefi

I bought a new asus b85mg mobo and processor for my new build ...
but i used my old hard drive, so that i dont have to backup my files or add a new os to it .. but after a sudden restart .. the windows got corrupted and now the system restarts when the windows logo appears... the dvd drive is showing up in the bios sata info and also the boot priority is set to the dvd drive .. i am new to ami uefi pls help ! Also i cant understand the new gui firmware, i guess the command prompt was better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it reaches the windows logo and then restarts its indeed finding your HD and trying to boot from it. Most likely the problem is that you moved the OS from one motherboard to another and now its chipset drivers and settings no longer match the hardware, causing it to crash and reboot on every boot attempt.

It is possible to move a Windows installation across motherboard hardware, but i don't recommend it as it involves quite a bit of fiddling around to get working. Better to backup important data, do a quick format of the OS partition (leave other partitions intact) and just reinstall windows of your on the newly formatted partition.

Comment: okay .... important documents is saved on my cloud , so actually i need to install a fresh win 7 os and for that i have set the boot priority to dvd writer but the disk never boots and goes into the hdd boot , i dont understand where i am going wrong.

Comment: Verify that the install media is working and can be booted from. This can be done by testing that you can boot from it in another computer.

Comment: yes already done on my laptop.. works good !

Comment: You may want to check whether the dvd unit is working properly then. Also, from your laptop you should be able to create a bootable USB stick to install windows from.

Comment: Wiped out the old mobo drivers and formatted the hdd ... now it works fine with the new build .. thanks mate your first solution helped me get through ! CHEERS